# how to create database using java code?

Tags: database, file

I want to create a database using java code, I have the database script file, I will read in a string and I will execute it but I want to know if I can use executequery or executeupdate???
and if this method is right or there is another one???

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, then try to solve the problem yourself and when you hit a specific issue post a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for the [executeUpdate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) method of the Statement interface is:

```
int executeUpdate(String sql)
                  throws SQLException
```

`executeUpdate` executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.

So to define a table or define an index, you would pass the SQL string to the `executeUpdate` method.

You can only execute one SQL statement at a time using the `executeUpdate` method, so if you're reading a file with more than one SQL statement, you'll have to parse the file and execute each SQL statement, one at a time.